# How can I prevent other applications from interrupting my game's exclusive fullscreen mode?

Tags: directx11, fullscreen

I am developing a game using D3D 11.

When I  got a pop-up message from a chat client (HipChat), my game's full screen mode is disabled because `IDXGISwapChain::Present` returns `DXGI_STATUS_OCCLUDED`. How can I avoid or prevent this? I don't want my game's exclusive full-screen access interrupted.

Comment: Considering that your commercial engine is likely to be under NDA, ask via internal support channels, or rephrase the question in a manner that makes it engine-agnostic.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have thought my question is a common problem in a game programming. But your advice helps me. Thanks.